Asse lekha Rav for a convert
Chalom,
How to apply Asse lekha Rav for a convert who is considered as his own rabbi

The sponsoring rabbi who teach him only during the conversion process
The local rabbi even he does not feel particulary close from him on hashkafa
a rabbi who he feels close on hashkafa even he is very far geographically?
Thank you


The key word is "lekha". Everyone, including converts, is free to choose their own rabbi.

Okay , so we must follow one rabbi ? The same for the Torah learning and halakha questions?

How is a convert considered his own rabbi?

@rosends I think it's a separate sentence: "Who is considered as his own rabbi?"
